# Q about with c++ switch and if program

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

hi im trying to do a program that gets a date from user checks if the date is correct 
and returns the date with month as a word
if the date is not correct the program should exit
but when i put numbers it dows nothing
plz help me

```
{
    int day,month,year;

    cout<<"enter day\n";
    cin>>day;
    cout<<"enter month\n";
    cin>>month;
    cout<<"enter year\n";
    cin>>year;
    if ( (   (((month==1)|| (month==3)|| (month==5)|| (month==7)|| (month==8)|| (month==10)|| (month==12) )&&((day<32)&&(day>0)))      ||      (((month==4)|| (month==6)|| (month==9)|| (month==11))&&((day<31)&&(day>0)))  ||  ((month==2)&&((day<29)&&(day>0)))  ) && ((year>-1)&&(year<3001))   )
     {
          switch(month)
          {
               case 1:
                   cout<<day<<"/"<<"january/"<<year;
                   break;
               case 2:
                   cout<<day<<"/"<<"febuary/"<<year;
                   break;

               case 3:
                   cout<<day<<"/"<<"march/"<<year;
                   break;

               case 4:
                    cout<<day<<"/"<<"april/"<<year;
                    break;

               case 5:
                    cout<<day<<"/"<<"may/"<<year;
                    break;

               case 6:
                    cout<<day<<"/"<<"june/"<<year;
                    break;

               case 7:
                   cout<<day<<"/"<<"july/"<<year;
                   break;

               case 8:
                   cout<<day<<"/"<<"August/"<<year;
                   break;

               case 9:
                   cout<<day<<"/"<<"September/"<<year;
                   break;

               case 10:
                   cout<<day<<"/"<<"October/"<<year;
                   break;

               case 11:
                   cout<<day<<"/"<<"November/"<<year;
                   break;

               case 12:
                   cout<<day<<"/"<<"December/"<<year;
                   break;

               default;
                   cout<<"not correct";
          }

      }
      else 
      {
          cout<<"false";
      }

      return 0;
};
```

Comment: What is the actual problem with the code? Also, all those extra consecutive blank lines just make it harder to look at the code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the if statement is too long!

Comment: It's unclear what your program is supposed to do.

Comment: the problam is that when i run the peogram and enter numbers it doest return anything..

Comment: cant i fix the if line?

Comment: Does it print at least "false" or something else ?

Comment: can you show me how plz?

Comment: no , nothing "press anything..."

Comment: Try to print your variables before entering in your condition.

Comment: Hmm. There are errors in this code. How did you execute it? Or did you retype it?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't even compile - "default;" should be "default:".

If that is fixed, and surrounded by the appropriate #include, using namespace std (yuk) and int main(int argc, char **argv), then it does compile and does output something.

There are a few bugs, though.

```
C:\>D:\Projects\temp\Debug\temp.exe
enter day
30
enter month
12
enter year
2000
30/December/2000not correct
C:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the array to dynamic and understandable codes**

```
int day,month,year;

std::string months [] = { "january" , "febuary" , "march" , "april" , "may" , "june" , "july" , "August" , "September" , "October" , "November" , "December" } ;

int total_day [12];
total_day [0] = 31;
total_day[1] = 29;
total_day[2] = 31;
total_day[3] = 30;
total_day[4] = 31;
total_day[5] = 30;
total_day[6] = 31;
total_day[7] = 31;
total_day[8] = 30;
total_day[9] = 31;
total_day[10] = 30;
total_day[11] = 31;

std::cout<<"enter day :\n";
std::cin>>day;
std::cout<<"enter month :\n";
std::cin>>month;
std::cout<<"enter year :\n";
std::cin>>year;

if ( (month > 0 && month <= 12) && (day > 0 && day <= total_day[month-1]) && (year > -1 && year < 3001))
{
    std::cout << day << "/"<< months[month-1] << "/" <<year;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Wrong Date";
}
```